# Need unique column in Union View

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, union, uniqueidentifier

I have a training application in which I need a union of two tables as a view in SQL Server. My company has a list of skills that are coded. Drilling is code 10, sanding is code 30, and so on. Employees are measured against these skill codes in our factory.
To illustrate, let's pick "Bob". Bob is a Metal Finisher who maintains several skills in the EmplSkills tables.

[image: View EmplSkills]

Secondly, in the JobSkills table are the skill requirements for "Metal Finisher".

[image: View JobSkills]

By comparing the two tables you can see that Bob's skills don't exactly match the requirements for his position as Metal Finisher  ...but they're pretty close.

However, from an AS9100 Quality Audit standpoint, I need to know exactly how close. I need all of Bob's skills that match the job requirements UNION'ed with all of Bob's ***extra*** skills that are not in the job scope but are nice-to-haves UNION'ed with all of Bob's ***missing*** skills that are extremely important to get trained up right away.

So, I'm creating the union view on the two tables with the SQL code below and
[image: here is the union-join result]
You can see that Bob can cut and deburr metal ...that's nice, but Bob has no sanding or scraping skills in his job position and that's very bad.

```
(SELECT a bunch of columns..., , row_number() over (order by t1.ref_no) as RowNum
   FROM emplskills as t1 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN jobskills as t2 on t1.skill_ID = t2.skill_ID 
  WHERE t2.skill_ID is null)
UNION
(SELECT the same bunch of columns..., , row_number() over (order by t1.ref_no) as RowNum
   FROM jobskills as t2 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN emplskills as t1 on t2.skill_ID = t1.skill_ID 
  WHERE t1.skill_ID is null)
 UNION
(SELECT the same bunch of columns..., , row_number() over (order by t1.ref_no) as RowNum
   FROM emplskills as t1, jobskills AS t2 
  WHERE t1.skill_ID=t2.skill_ID);
```

I'm using an application environment (Catavolt) in which all of the data tables need at least one unique data column that it uses remotely as a virtual "primary key" for its own housekeeping. So I need to **invent one column of unique values** and I can't figure out how to do this. I'd tried row_number () over (order by). I'd tried the two unique ref_no columns from each source table

```
SELECT ... , ((t1.ref_no*100000)+t2.ref_no) as UniqueKey
```

But the NULLs in the results blow out the math and I lose the uniqueness.

Is there something else I can add instead? It is of no consequence where the values come from, what they mean, or how big they are as long as they are unique.

TIA,
John

EDIT: RowNum suggestion from Tab on row_number() over (order by t1.ref_no)

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want your final resultset to look like.  If you really just need to add a made-up unique column to your existing results, you can use row_number().

Comment: thanks @TabAlleman but row_number() over (what?). Maybe that's what I'm not using correctly. Can you give me some code?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Based on your sample output, I'd row_number() over (order by ref_no)

Comment: Thanks @TabAlleman. Please see the EDIT in the post above. You can see that the result of row_num() over (order by t1.ref_no) is not unique.

Comment: Not sure how that would not be unique. ROW_NUMBER returns a new value for every row and they are all unique unless you include partitioning.

Comment: I don't follow @SeanLange. Are u saying row_number() over (order by 1)? That doesn't work.

Comment: The real challenge here is that we don't know what you want for output.

Comment: I think in your recent update you must have used partition by in your window function. Keep in mind we don't know your data structure or what you are trying to do here. All we have is a query and a screenshot of what it produces.  See the link I posted 20 minutes ago and give us some details. With that information we can help. Without it this is too much effort.

Comment: @JohnJoseph Looks like you added an individual row_number to each query in the UNION.   Obviously you need to add a single row_number to an outer query that SELECTs from your UNIONed queries.

Comment: Gotcha @SeanLange. Please look at my EDIT: added to the OP and look at that image. The last column "RowNum" (I just added) just needs unique values. I don't care what the values are, they just need to all be unique. I just tried row_number() over (order by t1.ref_no) in each of the 3 SELECT sections to generate that last column "RowNum". You can see that it is not unique.

Comment: Sigh....I would like to help you but I can't see your screen. Where is the query for that attempt? Where is the ddl and sample data? This would probably be really simple if you provided details.

Comment: @TabAlleman ok I think you nailed it. I can't use the row_number() 3 times in each of the union SELECTs. I need to have the row_number() column sit outside the overall union ONCE and somehow have the overall union nested inside. Can you provide some simple code structure to explain the nesting?

Comment: ok @SeanLange I editing my code in the OP with the row_number() adds so you can see how it is wrong. I know it's wrong now, but wanted you to see it.

Comment: Ahh yes. I wasn't sure if you had partitioning or multiple row_number functions. The important is if you understand **why** it was not what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it does sound like you really do just need to add an arbitrary unique column to your existing results, it's simply this:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {any column, really, it doesn't matter}) rn
FROM (
  {Your existing query}
) t
```

Comment: This is most likely what they need. For the order by you could even use a query to do something like order by (select 1).

Comment: DANG! that's it gentlemen, thank you! The out-board row_number (@TabAlleman) plus the select 1 (@SeanLange) did it. `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as RowNum FROM (my giant union) as T;`